# Pydrive: export doc as html

Tags: python, pydrive

I'm trying to export a .doc file as html from Google Drive into. Here is my code. I don't see anything in the documentation on how to download a doc as html. But here is my code so far from the examples. I'm not sure what the `docsfile` is referring to.

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()

drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)


test='https://docs.google.com/document/d/116rpW5DxfVDFTfJeCh3pFl9K8gtuZV5gX035631SKjm8/edit'
docsfile.GetContentFile(test, mimetype='text/html')
```

Comment: Is this all of your code? I'd be surprised if this ran without specifying what `docsfile` is.

Comment: this is what is posted as an example. it doesn't run obviously. here is the link https://github.com/googledrive/PyDrive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `docsfile` is the file you are intending to export, in your case the `.doc` file that already are in Google Drive.

```
docsfile = drive.CreateFile({'id': <ID of your file>)
```

You can see more about how to download files [here](http://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filemanagement.html#download-file-content). Here the full documentation http://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/

Alternatively, you can export your files as html using the [python client](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client) Google provides, directly:

```
    response = service.files().export(
        fileId=fileid, mimeType='text/html'
    ).execute()
    if response:
        with open(<full_path_of_your_destination_html_file>, 'wb') as fh:
            fh.write(response)
    else:
        <handle error here>
```

where `service` is something like:

```
    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(<path_to_your_credentials>)
    credentials = store.get()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)
```

see a full example on how to use the google client [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample).

Something to have in mind, your file in Google Drive must be a Google Doc (`application/vnd.google-apps.document`), not a doc file (`application/msword`), so you should be sure that the file was uploaded as a valid Google Doc.

Comment: This does not look like valid Python at the place it is being used: `mimeType=mimetype='text/html'`. In Python, attribution is a statement instead of an expression, and you can't use statements as arguments to function calls.

Comment: It was a typo @PauloScardine. Updated the response. Thanks